# Size of parenthesis ( ) in text mode

Tags: text-mode, parenthesis, size

Is known that you change the sizes of parenthesis in math mode, but in text mode?. For example, I have this situation:

```
(and there is open ball $B(x,\nicefrac{1}{i})$)
```

As you can see the two last parenthesis have the same size, but I want to distinguish the parenthesis for comment from parenthesis for equation putting the text mode parenthesis largest.

PD: Note the use of `nicefrac` package.

Comment: Is this a question about preference? Most certainly it has nothing to do with nicefrac.

Comment: The question is not related to `nicefrac` package, I just write about that package to be more precise in the code. You can see the tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I use `\scalerel*` to make a `(` as big as a `\strut` (any bigger and it will affect line spacing).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,nicefrac}
\begin{document}
\scalerel*{(}{\strut}and there is open ball $B(x,\nicefrac{1}{i})$\scalerel{)}{\strut}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one prefers a stretched rather than scaled version, just use `\stretchrel` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,nicefrac}
\begin{document}
\stretchrel*{(}{\strut}and there is open ball $B(x,\nicefrac{1}{i})$\stretchrel{)}{\strut}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Technically speaking, the `\scalerel`'ed paren is actually in math mode, but I confirmed that it typesets no different than a text mode version (`\scalerel` can force its argument into text mode by literally enclosing the argument between `$` signs).

Comment: The second image correspond to the code above?

Comment: @juanuni in the 2nd image, the taller parens are slightly narrower than in the 1st image.  indeed, 2nd code block produced 2nd image

Comment: I can not distinguish the difference :S

Comment: @juanuni  If you compile `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,nicefrac}
\begin{document}
\scalerel*{(}{\strut}and there is open ball $B(x,\nicefrac{1}{i})$\scalerel{)}{\strut}\par
\stretchrel*{(}{\strut}and there is open ball $B(x,\nicefrac{1}{i})$\stretchrel{)}{\strut}
\end{document}`, you will see the 2nd line is slightly shorter width.

Comment: Ok, I can see the difference, but with magnifying glass efect, anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: @juanuni to further clarify, I can set scaled and stretched versions in two separate boxes and measure the box width.  The scaled paren width is 4.6669pt, whereas the stretched paren width is 3.88907pt.

Comment: And how you get that info?

Comment: `\setbox0=\hbox{\scalerel*{(}{\strut}}\the\wd0\quad
\setbox0=\hbox{\stretchrel*{(}{\strut}}\the\wd0`

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `\big`-related stretching for brackets:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\newcommand{\textbiglparen}{$\bigl($}
\newcommand{\textbigrparen}{$\bigr)$}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
Here is some text (and there is open ball $B(x,\nicefrac{1}{i})$). \par
Here is some text \textbiglparen{}and there is open ball $B(x,\nicefrac{1}{i})$\textbigrparen.
\end{document}
```

In my opinion the original (non-scaled) setting is still acceptable.

Comment: Maybe is only about preferences. But you may notice with scaled setting you can read a little bit more clearly the math. If this can help to the readers, I want make it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply temporarily switch the font to a larger one, say, using `relsize`.  Still, [Steven's stretchrel'ed parens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249678) look most economical to me so far, when compared to scalerel'd parens, relsized parens, and [Werner's math-mode parens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249685):

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}% thanks to egreg
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}\noindent
Here is some text (and there is open ball \(B(x,\nicefrac{1}{i})\)).\\
Here is some text \stretchrel*{(}{\strut}and there is open ball \(B(x,\nicefrac{1}{i})\)\stretchrel*{)}{\strut}.\\
Here is some text \textlarger[.5]{(}and there is open ball \(B(x,\nicefrac{1}{i})\)\textlarger[.5]{)}.\\
Here is some text \(\bigl(\)and there is open ball \(B(x,\nicefrac{1}{i})\)\(\bigr)\).\\
Here is some text \scalerel*{(}{\strut}and there is open ball \(B(x,\nicefrac{1}{i})\)\scalerel*{)}{\strut}.\\
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I am asking for proper™ big parens in [text mode native big parens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674612/text-mode-native-big-parens) .