# text mode native big parens

Tags: brackets, text-mode

Continuing https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/674616, can we get big text-mode round parens for

1. [`pdf`]`latex`, or
2. {`xe`|`lua`}`latex`

natively (i.e., without scaling/stretching as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249678 or jumping to math mode as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249685)?

To take an example to play with, run `pdflatex` on

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
We can complain about zillions of \LaTeX\ issues \(\Bigl(\)but we love it \(\bigl(\)and so we refrain from complaining that much (unless we have suggestions)\(\bigr)\Bigr)\).
\end{document}
```

to obtain

[image: output]

My hope is that native big parens would have proper spacing to adjacent letters and have a similar look (which is not a problem in the above above example with Computer Modern (but can be a problem if the math and text fonts differ too much)).

Before you ask: I've already tried out `\textlarger[.5]{()}` and `\textlarger[1]{()}` using `relsize` and NewTX.  I'm unsure whether anything better exists.

Comment: for similar look you require a font that matches your text to have extendable parens, this is likely to only be the case in math fonts, so switching to math is quite natural here, not just a latex syntax quirk

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Math-font parens may be quite different from text-font parens because the math and text fonts may differ. So switching to maths *in general* may produce nonsimilar parens (and yes, you're right that one needs similar fonts if you do switch). I'm afraid I don't understand you point.

Comment: latex can only use an extended character if the font provides it and only math fonts  do that. Otherwise you just use the font at a larger size, which you could do for any letter. as egreg shows in his answer, but that is quite unlike using an extendable character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different font size for the parentheses, specifying how bigger (in pt).

Explanation: when LaTeX is typesetting, it maintains in `\f@size` the current font size as a pure number (with `pt` implied). So we can add to it; the braces around the `\fontsize` declaration keep the change local.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tbig}{mm}
 {% #1 = decimal number, #2 = fence
  {\fontsize{\fp_eval:n{\use:c{f@size}+#1}}{0}\selectfont#2}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

We can complain about zillions of \LaTeX\ issues
\tbig{1.5}(but we love it \tbig{1}(and so we refrain from
complaining that much (unless we have suggestions)\tbig{1})\tbig{1.5}).

\end{document}
```

For CM fonts, you need `fix-cm` to allow using fonts at every size.

[image]

Here's the same with NewTX

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tbig}{mm}
 {% #1 = decimal number, #2 = fence
  {\fontsize{\fp_eval:n{\use:c{f@size}+#1}}{0}\selectfont#2}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

We can complain about zillions of \LaTeX\ issues 
\tbig{1.5}(but we love it \tbig{1}(and so we refrain from 
complaining that much (unless we have suggestions)\tbig{1})\tbig{1.5}).

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: two-column format is used just to make smaller pictures.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!